# Is there a schematic for the ESP32S Dev Kit C V4 NodeMCU WLAN Development Board?

Tags: esp32

Recently I bought a ESP32S Dev Kit C V4 NodeMCU WLAN Development Board. I got it from azdelivery.de in Germany.
Now I am interested in the schematic for this board to learn more about it. Not Google, nor the support team at azdelivery.de could help me, but since the board is a Chinese mass product, I hope to find an answer here, where I could get the schematic.
Thank you!

[image: Picture]

Comment: Apparently az-delivery have [a free e-book available for download](https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/esp-32-dev-kit-c-v4-1?variant=32519652409440) on this ESP32 board. Have you looked at that? [There's also a generic ESP32 Devkit C V4 schematic available](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I also have the e-book. It contains a general description of the board, the pinout, many technical details and some example sketches, but unfortunately no schematic of the board. The link with the schematic is new to me! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Here is a webpage that provides ESP32 Devkit C schematic and pin definition. It may help you. But not sure if the dev board you got is same as the web provides. [ESP32 Devkit C schematic](https://esp32cube.com/esp32/esp32_dev_board.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I’ll check that, when I’m back home again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espressif has schematics and more on their website. EZ-Delivery sells two different versions: One has a CP2101 USB-Interface, the other one uses a CH340 instead. If you have the CP2101 variant, this should match the one at Espressif's Website:

https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf

More related docs are linked on their Website (scroll down to "Related Documents" here:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/hw-reference/esp32/get-started-devkitc.html#get-started-esp32-devkitc-board-front

Answer (score 1):

Here is a webpage that provides ESP32 Devkit C schematic and pin definition.

[image]

[ESP32 Devkit C schematic](https://esp32cube.com/esp32/esp32_dev_board.html)

Comment: OP's board is definitely not having a xQFN28 CP2102N USB chip.